# Game Running Slow on Phone but great on Computer

Tags: c#, mobile, unity-game-engine, touch

I am writing a simple puzzle game resembling the game three's but with all two's in it. Its blazing fast in the editor but it is not running properly on my phone. This is the code I wrote for Swipe Detection in Update() Method is there anything wrong with this ? Note TouchComplete is a Global Variable

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (0);
        switch (touch.phase) {
        case TouchPhase.Began:
            touchStart = touch.position;
            TouchComplete = false;
            break;
        case TouchPhase.Moved:
            if (TouchComplete)
                return;
            Vector2 deltaPostion = touch.position - touchStart;
            if (Mathf.Abs (deltaPostion.x) < SWIPE_THRESHHOLD || Mathf.Abs (deltaPostion.y) < SWIPE_THRESHHOLD)
                return;
            if (Mathf.Abs (deltaPostion.x) > Mathf.Abs (deltaPostion.y)) {
                if (deltaPostion.x > 0) {
                    RightSwipe ();
                } else {
                    LeftSwipe ();
                }
            } else {
                if (deltaPostion.y > 0) {
                    UpSwipe ();
                } else {
                    DownSwipe ();
                }
            }
            TouchComplete = true;
            break;
        default:
            TouchComplete = true;
            break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you think this is the problem?

Comment: Because when I just use touch.deltaPosition to detect swipe it works at the same speed @Almo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the target Frame Rate set to 30 on Mobile Devices, for the animation effects to be smooth I set the `Application.targetFrameRate = 1000` and it worked fine.